# Не работает отправка вложенных приложений

Tags: php, mvc, phpmailer

Помогите пожалуйста - не могу понять в чем причина. Данные из полей отправляются на почту а приложение нет.
PhpMailer установлен через композер. Реализация на MVC.

Спасибо за помощь!

**Модель:**

```
<?php

class Mail{

public static function sendOneEmail($email, $subject, $body){
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); //создаем экземпляр класса
    $mail->addAttachment($path);
    $mail->IsSMTP(); //включаем SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.yandex.ua';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // включаем аутентификацию по SMTP
    $mail->Port = 587; // 465 or 587 устанавливаем SMTP порт
    $mail->Username = '559912@yandex.ru';  //ваша почта
    $mail->Password = 'qwerty';  //пароль
    $mail->SetFrom('559912@yandex.ru');
    //$mail->AddReplyTo(('email@yandex.ru', 'Вася Пупкин');
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // отправка в виде HTML
    $mail->CharSet='utf-8'; //кодировка письма
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->Send();


if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);
}        
    }

}
```

**Контроллер:**

```
<?php

class ContactsController extends Controller{

public function __construct($data = array()){
    parent::__construct($data);
    $this->model = new Message();
}   

public function index(){
    if ( $_POST ){
        $mail = new Mail();
        $company_name = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['company_name']));
        $contact_name = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['contact_name']));
        $phone = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['phone']));
        $email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));            
        $file = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['file']));



        $message = "Название компании: $company_name"."<br>"."Контактное лицо: $contact_name"."<br>"."Контактный телефон: $phone"."<br>".
            "E-mail: $email"."<br>"."Приложение: $file"."<br>";
        $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");


        Mail::sendOneEmail('559912@yandex.ru', 'Заявка', $message);
        header("Location: /?success");

    }
}

public function admin_index(){
    $this->data = $this->model->getList();
}   
}
```

Comment: Сами отладчиком проходили? Точно попадает внутрь if где `$mail->AddAttachment`?

Comment: А в чём смысл делать `AddAttachment`  после `Send`?

Comment: @A K да попадает.

Comment: @Мелкий `AddAttachment` идет перед `Send`. Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Victor     `$mail->Send(); if (isset($_FILES['file'])` ;)

Comment: Перед `Send` идёт E_NOTICE за обращение к неизвестной переменной. Да, тот AddAttachment я не заметил. Но вряд ли получая null этот вызов делает что-то осмысленное. Зато какой отладчик? Вы даже предупреждения интерпретатора не смотрите. Проверьте свой error_reporting.